# backup plan on ubuntu server (filesystem/mysql)

Tags: backup

I finished configuring my first production server, and I'm thinking about strategy to backup data.

In my head this task has 3 faces.

1. Filesystem (ubuntu itself)
2. Mysql
3. webroot

Strategy
1. Every 6 month tarball Filesystem and save it to remote server in other location.
2. Every sunday create sql dump and save to remote server
3. No need to backup, webroot is on SVN remote server.

What do you think about this?

Now my question is, how do I scp tar/dump files to remote server in secure way? I will have to create little shell script that would make backup files automatically and move them to remote, but that will require putting ssh access directly in plain file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LVM, make a snapshot of volumes you need with `lvcreate -s`, then `dd or tar > gzip > rsync` to remote location.

`mysqldump > gzip > rsync` is fine if your DB isn't under heavy load. Use cron for scheduling backups.

For secure transfer you don't need to have a password somewhere in plain text.
Use `rsync` over ssh with rsa-key auth, that's it.

*Please, at least try to do research yourself, before asking questions here. This is really trivial stuff.*